# In phonegap project, how to integrate close button in popup window

Tags: android, jquery, url, cordova, popup

In my phonegap Android project I want to open external files in popup.Using window.open files are get opened but my issue is that I need a close button in the opened window,so that user can close the window and return back to app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cordova **[InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/dev/doc/index.md)**

```
window.open('http://www.google.co.in','_blank','location=yes','closebuttoncaption=CLOSE');
```

Before using inappbrowser you must install the plugin to your project.

To add inappbrowser to project by commanline

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

**UPDATE**

In android InAppBrowser wont shows Done/Close button without the location toolbar, to enable the toolbar put `'location=yes'` in window.open

There is another way, if you dont want to show the location/url

just comment these lines of codes in **InAppBrowser.java** class

```
 toolbar.addView(actionButtonContainer);
 toolbar.addView(edittext);
 toolbar.addView(close);

 // Don't add the toolbar if its been disabled
 if (getShowLocationBar()) {
     // Add our toolbar to our main view/layout
     main.addView(toolbar);
 }
```

and **put this**

```
 toolbar.addView(actionButtonContainer);
 if (getShowLocationBar()) {
     toolbar.addView(edittext);
 }
 toolbar.addView(close);

 // Add our toolbar to our main view/layout
 main.addView(toolbar);
```

This will shows a **Close** button.